# Access localhost during Docker Build MacOS host.docker.internal throws Connection Refused error

Tags: docker

I am building my docker image on Docker for Mac where I need to install some gems from the local gem repository hosted on localhost:9292.

I have this in my Dockerfile

```
RUN gem install patron -v 0.10.0 --source http://host.docker.internal:9292
```

However, the gem install does not complete and throws a `Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused` error.
I also tried to curl to the `host.docker.internal` and that throws an error `Failed to connect to host.docker.internal port 9292: Connection refused`

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds) `host.docker.internal` works only in development (although I do not know how Docker daemon determinse if it's running on production or not). My guess is that your Docker daemon runs in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

try --add-host=google.com:127.0.0.1 in your build command. It worked for me in ubuntu. I was able to see the ip to google.com as specified in the cmd. just replace the dns and ip

for your case:

--add-host=host.docker.internal:127.0.0.1

Comment: I am trying to access the localhost from the container, what should I replace for dns and port

Comment: @VishakhaLall, i've edited my post for your use case

Comment: This will not work for macOS, host.docker.internal is supposed to point to the localhost

Comment: @VishakhaLall, how is it supposed to point to the localhost? if you make some entry in your /etc/hosts and then use that url during build, does it get resolved according to your hosts file? i think not

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds this explains the networking in Docker for MacOS

Comment: @VishakhaLall, that explains for when the container is "running" not when you "build" an image.

Comment: I tried it, did not work, perhaps because the Docker Daemon on MacOS runs on a VM on top of the host, not directly on the host

Comment: @VishakhaLall, how about you directly write 127.0.0.1 instead of the url?

Comment: How will that work? 127.0.0.1 points to the VM on which the Daemon runs not the host network

Comment: sorry, my bad. But i was just thinking, since the docker daemon runs on a VM, can you check your VirtualBox(or whatever it is on mac) for any VM an perhaps you could set port mappings there.